# Is there a Rotate Tool in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, editing

I can see the move tool. But coming across versions, i did not see any Rotate tool in Quantum GIS. As a hardcore feature editor myself, i have found it rather difficult. Am i missing something obvious?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322262/rotating-shape-around-defined-point-instead-of-centroid-in-qgis

Answer (score 14):

Use the  Plugins>Fetch Python Plugins and select:

**Rectangles, Ovals and Diamonds**

Edit your layer (polygon)

[image]

and select a feature to rotate - click and hold on the edge and the shape will rotate.
[image]

Comment: I believe the plugin you are referring to is 'Rectangles ovals digitizing,' not 'Rectangles, Ovals and Diamonds.'

Comment: Rectangles, Ovals and Diamonds (0.1.7) in the list on QGIS 1.8 is a new name to Rectangles Oval Digitizing - http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/10/21/easy-rectangles-circles-and-ellipses-in-qgis/

Comment: Those plugins are by similar authors, but do different things. Rectangles, Ovals and Diamonds creates features based on an available point layer and attributes and outputs to a new shapefile. Rectangles Ovals Digitizing offers the digitizing tools available when editing a layer (offering the rotate function you describe). You have both installed, as seen in your first screen snap.

Comment: as i checked, It can only rotate Polygon features, and only one feature at a time..it is called 'rect,ovals and digitizing'

Comment: whatever works - the point is that it does 'rotate' which was the GISse question.

Comment: this tool and the cadTool plugin seem to rotate single features..but unlike the move tool where one can do several at a time, here only one is possible..hope they come up with something good soon..

Answer (score 11):

The current developement version(1.9.0) of QGis has a visual interactive rotate tool that can rotate multiple selected features at a time just like we can do with the move tool. If you are using OsGeo4W instlaler, you should be able to see this tool(In Advanced Digitizing Toolbar) in the current version.

[image]

**Edit:**

QGIS 2.0 onwards have the above mentioned rotate tool built in.

Answer (score 7):

You can rotate features with the **qgsAffine** plugin.

It's part of the *QGIS Contributed Repository*.

Having a rotate tool on the editor toolbar would be a plus.
Here is the feature request from hub.qgis.org

http://hub.qgis.org/issues/3472

Comment: qgsAffine though useful, is painful to use..

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is easily possible to rotate (and therefore mirror to a certain extent) a layer in QGIS (2+) without PYQGIS.

To do this, you need to enable the Advanced Digitizing Toolbar, by right clicking on the blank toolbar and enabling it:

[image: Toolbar menu]

Now, with editing on, select the Rotate Feature(s) tool and click on the feature you want to rotate. You can do this interactively or by entering a degree value and hitting Enter:

[image: rotate tool in action]

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [CadTools](http://www.catais.org/qgis/cadtools/) plugin **Rotate Feature** tool:

[image]

> "This function is for rotating features. You first have to select the
> feature you want to rotate and a vertex which will be the centre of
> rotation. The vertex does not have to be on the current layer.
>
> After selecting the feature and the vertex you can enter the angle of
> rotation (in degrees)."

**Caveats**

- There is only numeric input for rotation (no visual-feedback dragging or snapping), though that may be a good thing depending upon your needs.
- The rotated objects are *duplicated* to a new 'CadLayer ...' layer. You will need to copy/paste features back to your source data set. This is a nice non-destructive means of editing, but labor-intensive for many rotations.
- The copy/pasted duplicate objects do not retain any attribute data. Think of it as new feature creation, not a manipulation of existing geometries.

Answer (score 2):

When you install the QAD plugin (dedicated AutoCAD interface for QGIS), then you can simply type the `RO` command in your command box.

[image]