# Are There Any OpenSource GIS Software Programs With an "Interactive" Rotate Feature Option?

Tags: open-source-gis, vector, features

![Rotate feature option][1]Sorry if the question is too simple, but are there any open source GIS software programs available with an interactive "Rotate vector feature"  option?

Eg : ArcGIS has it in Editor\Rotate.  Manifold has it in Transform toolbar (but its only angle based, not interative) .

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29241/is-there-a-rotate-tool-in-qgis

Comment: Thanks mapperz, I was able to use QGIS plugin " Rectangles Ovals digitizing"  to edit and rotate selected polygons.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenJUMP](http://www.openjump.org/) has a rotate tool in the editing toolbar that lets you 'interactively' rotate a selection.

Comment: Thanks Darren, but I think Openjump has less capabilities in raster display, I will need to rotate the feature based on underlying image. Thanks for the hint anyway.