# Drawing squares in PostGIS layers at different angles

Tags: qgis, postgis, vector

I am trying to draw two squares on a 45-degree angle and then merge them using PostGIS to edit. QGIS can draw squares but only on a perpendicular plane (eg, 0, 90, 180), and I need to be able to draw at different angles (eg, 45-degrees).

Comment: The problem description is still too vague to offer you good answers. Please provide a description and sketches of what you are trying to do. Then we can suggest relevant tools for the job.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29241/is-there-a-rotate-tool-in-qgis

Answer (score 3):

I googled "qgis diamond" and found that there is a plugin that will supposedly do this.  Go here: http://pyqgis.org/repo/contributed and scroll down to "Rectangles, Ovals, Diamonds : 0.1.7".  Haven't tried it though.

Comment: It works just fine.  I use it regularly. See Mapperz link in the comments above.  One small idosyncracy seems to be if you have edited or created new geometry, even when you save it, the plugin doesn't always seem to recognize the changes.  You can get around that by just removing and re-adding the relevant layer.  Otherwise, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

That's default QGIS behavior: Editing and PostGIS connections are available in the core application.

Comment: One more correction that I received - the tool has to be able to edit from PostGIS...

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you want to do, then we worry about PostGIS.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called Digitizing or Editing. Have you looked at the digitizing toolbar? Also have a look at the [Digitizing an existing layer](http://docs.qgis.org/html/en/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#digitizing-an-existing-layer) section from the Qgis user manual.

You can create new features in various types of vector layers, including a PostGIS layer.

You should add your PostGIS data to your map, and then toggle editing. After that you can start digitizing and adding new features.