# Rotate polygon preserving topology in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

Is it possible in QGIS? What I need is:

1) Rotate a polygon inside another one (bigger), obviously the polygons are not overlapped.
2) Rotate a given polygon in a topologically correct layer (like a cadastral parcels layer)

What I would like to avoid is make holes, merge polygon pieces, etc. (the "old way").

Comment: does this functionality exist in any other application? Would the adjacent polygons have shape distortion after this polygon is rotated?

Comment: Have you read http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/29241/1897?

Comment: What does "the old way" mean? And if you rotate a polygon in a parcels layer its going to overlap the others (unless its like a square and you rotate 90 degrees) and then what do you want to do? Sorry, but this is unclear to me. Can you make it clearer?