# Mirror or rotate layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am trying to **mirror or rotate(180) my layer** some thing like  this "**-->**" to this "**<--**".
Is there any built in plugin or support available to do this job or i have to write code in **pyqgis**?

I don't know what the exctly term is better to asked either it is invert, filp, rotate or mirror.

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Is there a Rotate Tool in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29241/is-there-a-rotate-tool-in-qgis)

Comment: Are you wanting the flip a line direction start and end vertices?

Comment: @Joseph, they're discussing a much older version of QGIS, their advice is quite out of date.

Comment: @coneypylon - Good point but those plugins mentioned are still available in the newer QGIS versions :)

Comment: @Joseph That's true. I wrote up an answer on the built in tool, though, since that is not discussed in the other post. I think I'll cross-post it in case people go looking for an answer for this on Google.

Comment: @coneypylon Do not cross-answer. The correct process for this is to vote as duplicate of the other.