# Rotating label in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, rotate

I have a Shapefile of cartographic text (roads, buildings, water  etc) and I would like to be able to rotate individual road names to fit within the width of the road. Anyway, I know it is possible to rotate a feature in QGIS using the Advanced Digitizing Toolbar ([Is there a Rotate Tool in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29241/is-there-a-rotate-tool-in-qgis/29247#29247)), however when I use this feature it doesnt seem to rotate at all (St Nicholas Avenue, below).

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Usually, one would rotate the labels, not the features. Else, one would rotate the entire map (that is, north is not straight up but at an angle). It sound very wrong to rotate each features, as it would change their coordinates (making the data close to useless)

Comment: can you join the point attribute to the road type and label via the linear/polygon direction?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I think that is possible. Take a look in the properties of the Layer and go to Labels. Select the underpoint "Placement" form the list with Text, Formating, Buffer, ... there can you find under "Data defined" the Rotation. Define a field in the attribute table for the roation.

Now you can use the **Label Toolbar** for rotating the text.

[image: Add a field to store the angle for the rotation.]

Comment: and there is a "Layer to labeled layer " (http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/toLabeledLayer/)  Plugin which does the things described by Cartographer for you (making fields vor offsetx, offsety and rotation) and setting the datadefined overriding...