# Rotating shape around defined point instead of centroid in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, rotate, drawing

The rotate feature in QGIS 3 rotates shapes around the centroid of that shape (with our without a defined angle).

When I start to rotate, I see that a cross appears at the centroid of that shape.

***I would like to move that cross to rotate the shape around that cross.***

I tried to move the cross with both left mouse clicks (no solution) and right mouse clicks (QGIS crashes after this action).

Are there any known ways to rotate shapes (just as in ArcMap) around a given point?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To rotate feature(s) in QGIS you need to be in editing mode, select one or more features then use Rotate feature tool:
 [image]
, also found in edit menu.

While holding `ctrl` left click to move rotation centroid. I couldnt find a way to snap roatation centroid to points but you can zoom in very far to get sub milimeter accuracy. When satisfied with location just left click to start rotating (free or by typing in angle).

For certain similar task also plugin [Vector Bender](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/VectorBender/)  can be useful, it "Does to vectors what georefencers does to raster"

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Mat I did not know you could do this so thank you also. Much more efficient than the native tool I suggested.

Answer (score 6):

In QGIS 3 you can use the native rotate tool which can be found in the toolbox. Here you can specify an anchor point by clicking on the map in order to rotate around it at a specified  degree clockwise.

[image]